# Chrome keeps loading a webpage (spinning wheel) for long; no issue in Firefox for the same pages

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Chrome version: 108.0.5359.125 64bit
OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2

Since some dais Chrome (browser) keeps loading every webpage (spinning wheel doesn't stop), the same webpages on Firefox are okay.

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this happen in Incognito mode?

Comment: It doesn't happen in incognito mode.

Comment: Then it's either a browser extension you have installed or some cache and cookies that Chrome has for this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the Chrome data for this site:

1. Go to the site in Google Chrome, and then **click the padlock**-shaped symbol to the left corner of the address bar (*If the site doesn’t have a secure connection to your web browser, you will see a ‘Not secure’ label in place of the padlock-shaped icon—click it instead*):
   [image]
2. On the context menu that shows up, click **Site Settings**:
   [image]
3. Chrome will load a new tab listing site-related usage data and permissions. Click the button labeled **Clear Data** under the Usage section:
   [image]
4. Click **Clear** on the confirmation pop-up. Chrome will immediately clear the cache and cookies for the site:
   [image]
5. Refresh the website and see if it helped.

---

If that didn't help, another thing to try is to disable the Chrome Extensions you may have installed in your browser.

1. Go to the Chrome three dots menu > More tools > Extensions
2. Toggle all items there to be disabled (white/gray instead of blue):
   [image]
3. Refresh the website and see if it helped
4. If it did, you can then try to re-enable those Chrome extensions one by one (while checking the site in between) to try to track down which extension was the cause